# AWS QuickSight: Calculate Aggregate Percentage in Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

In QuickSight I would like to calculate the aggregate percentage of one column against the aggregate total of another column.

Imagine the following data-set structure:

```
group|dim1|dim2|total|remaining
```

I would like to have a table Visualization with the following structure:

```
group-by-group|sum(total)|sum(remaining)|sum(remaining)/sum(total)
```

I would also like to dynamically filter via controls based on dim1 and dim2. This makes pre-calculating any percentages problematic. Is there a way to do this in QuickSight? I can visually represent it with a `Stacked 100% Bar Chart`, but I'd prefer to have this in-line with the rest of the data in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [aggregate functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/calculated-field-aggregations.html) in a [calculated field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-calculated-field-analysis.html). The resulting field well groups/values would be:

Group:

- `group-by-group`

Values:

- `total` aggregation=sum
- `remaining` aggregation=sum
- `percent_remaining` aggregation=custom

Where `percent_remaining` would be a calculated field with the following formula:
`sum({remaining})/sum({total})`

The aggregate `sum` functions are calculated at visualization render time and take filters into account.